# SAS copy task download speed

Tags: sas

When copying the files through EG copy task what is the average download speed? Is it based on the internet speed? I’m asking since I know it follows FTP, so is there a limitation on the packets sent and received?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you copying from a local machine server, local network server or remote network server? Is your EG machine connected through wifi? Server OS or intermediate hops might also impose throttling. EG copy would certainly be slower than say a FileZilla multi-connection download

Comment: I don't really understand the question as you ask it - what are you trying to actually find out?  What's the action you'll take based on the information?